# swift calculate distance between two locations

Tags: swift, macos, mapkit

I would like to get the distance between two locations.
I tried this code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
   CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString("ADDRESS OF LOC 2") {    (placemarks, error) in
   guard let placemarks = placemarks, let loc2 = placemarks.first?.location
      else {
         return
      }


    let loc1 = CLLocation(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    var distance = loc1.distance(from: loc2)
    print((distance/1000).rounded(), " km")
     }
}
```

My problem is that i get a wrong distance.
The print result will be "2 km"

If i calculate the distance between the same locations in "Maps" I get two route options with the length "2,7 km" and "2,9 km"

What did i wrong?

Comment: you are not getting anything wrong, you just dropped the decimal part by using rounded() method , i.e. 2.7 km becomes 2 km because you rounded it off!!

Comment: if i do this: `print(distance/1000)` the result will be: `1.74364568832` - that isn't the same like 2,7 or 2,9 :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distance):

> This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account specific altitude changes between the two locations.

So you're calculating straight line distance, "as the crow flies", not following roads, which would lead to a longer route, as you're seeing in Maps. You'd need something like MapKit's [`MKDirectionsRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkdirectionsrequest) to match the route you see in the Maps app. [Ray Wenderlich has a good tutorial.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110054/routing-mapkit-core-location)

Here's an example I just knocked up that works in a macOS Playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

// As we're waiting for completion handlers, don't want the playground
// to die on us just because we reach the end of the playground.
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269573/xcode-error-domain-dvtplaygroundcommunicationerrordomain-code-1
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.geocodeAddressString("1 Pall Mall East, London SW1Y 5AU") { (placemarks: [CLPlacemark]? , error: Error?) in
    if let placemarks = placemarks {
        let start_placemark = placemarks[0]
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString("Buckingham Palace, London SW1A 1AA", completionHandler: { ( placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) in
            if let placemarks = placemarks {
                let end_placemark = placemarks[0]

                // Okay, we've geocoded two addresses as start_placemark and end_placemark.
                let start = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: start_placemark.location!.coordinate))
                let end = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: end_placemark.location!.coordinate))

                // Now we've got start and end MKMapItems for MapKit, based on the placemarks. Build a request for 
                // a route by car.
                let request: MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
                request.source = start
                request.destination = end
                request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.automobile

                // Execute the request on an MKDirections object
                let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
                directions.calculate(completionHandler: { (response: MKDirectionsResponse?, error: Error?) in
                    // Now we should have a route.
                    if let routes = response?.routes {
                        let route = routes[0]
                        print(route.distance) // 2,307 metres.
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh okay, and how can i get the distance with "following roads"?

Comment: the Ray Weinerlich tutorial is for iOS, is this a problem?

Comment: @Ghost108 Ah, I hadn't spotted you were using macOS—I tend to think of iOS when I think of Swift because it's been a long time since I did macOS development! I believe the MapKit principles are similar on both platforms, though, so it should hopefully give you a decent hint as to what you need to do.

Comment: @Ghost108 I just threw together an example in my answer that runs for me in a playground on my Mac. Hopefully that should give you an idea of what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you want travel distance rather than "as the crow flies", use `MKDirections`, e.g.:

```
func routes(to item: MKMapItem, completion: @escaping ([MKRoute]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let request = MKDirections.Request()
    request.source = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()
    request.destination = item
    request.transportType = .automobile

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
    directions.calculate { response, error in
        completion(response?.routes, error)
    }
}
```

And if you want to format to one decimal place, I'd suggest using `NumberFormatter`, so it's appropriately formatted for international users for whom the decimal separator is not `.`:

```
self.routes(to: item) { routes, error in
    guard let routes = routes, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1

    for route in routes {
        let distance = route.distance / 1000
        print(formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: distance))!, "km")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using MapKit & Swift 5

**Calculate distance between two location location, It will help anyone**

Sample Function : I have tested in Google Map as well as Apple Map

```
        let startLocation : CLLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: 23.0952779, longitude: 72.5274129)
        let endLocation : CLLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: 23.0981711, longitude: 72.5294229)
        let distance = startLocation.distance(from: endLocation)
        self.getDistance(departureDate: Date().adjust(hour: 8, minute: 0, second: 0, day: 0, month: 0), arrivalDate: Date().adjust(hour: 8, minute: 10, second: 0, day: 0, month: 0), startLocation: startLocation, endLocation: endLocation) { (distanceInMeters) in

            print("fake distance: \(distance)")
            let fakedistanceInMeter = Measurement(value: distance, unit: UnitLength.meters)
            let fakedistanceInKM = fakedistanceInMeter.converted(to: UnitLength.kilometers).value
            let fakedistanceInMiles = fakedistanceInMeter.converted(to: UnitLength.miles).value
            print("fakedistanceInKM :\(fakedistanceInKM)")
            print("fakedistanceInMiles :\(fakedistanceInMiles)")


            print("actualDistance : \(distanceInMeters)")

            let distanceInMeter = Measurement(value: distanceInMeters, unit: UnitLength.meters)
            let distanceInKM = distanceInMeter.converted(to: UnitLength.kilometers).value
            let distanceInMiles = distanceInMeter.converted(to: UnitLength.miles).value
            print("distanceInKM :\(distanceInKM)")
            print("distanceInMiles :\(distanceInMiles)")
        }
```

Use of functions

```
                    self.getDistance(departureDate: trip.departure.dateTime, arrivalDate: trip.arrival.dateTime, startLocation: startLocation, endLocation: endLocation) { (actualDistance) in
                        print("actualDistance : \(actualDistance)")
                    }
```

**I am improved above function and added code here, I hope it will help someone.**

```
func calculateDistancefrom(departureDate: Date, arrivalDate: Date, sourceLocation: MKMapItem, destinationLocation: MKMapItem, doneSearching: @escaping (_ distance: CLLocationDistance) -> Void) {

        let request: MKDirections.Request = MKDirections.Request()

        request.departureDate = departureDate
        request.arrivalDate = arrivalDate

        request.source = sourceLocation
        request.destination = destinationLocation

        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
        request.transportType = .automobile

        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
        directions.calculate { (directions, error) in
            if var routeResponse = directions?.routes {
                routeResponse.sort(by: {$0.expectedTravelTime <
                    $1.expectedTravelTime})
                let quickestRouteForSegment: MKRoute = routeResponse[0]

                doneSearching(quickestRouteForSegment.distance)
            }
        }
    }

    func getDistance(departureDate: Date, arrivalDate: Date, startLocation : CLLocation, endLocation : CLLocation, completionHandler: @escaping (_ distance: CLLocationDistance) -> Void) {

        let destinationItem =  MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: startLocation.coordinate))
        let sourceItem      =  MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: endLocation.coordinate))
        self.calculateDistancefrom(departureDate: departureDate, arrivalDate: arrivalDate, sourceLocation: sourceItem, destinationLocation: destinationItem, doneSearching: { distance in
            completionHandler(distance)
        })
    }
```